# In a form with a tabbed control, a button click reduces panel-height in tab page in focus, which gets corrected if move to another tab and come back

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a fixed size form containing a tabcontrol component, which has two tab pages. The tab pages contain panels with tables which may contain a variable amount of data to be displayed. When I press a 'Refresh' button, in its event handler, I reinitialize the values in the table. So far, I do not recalculate the height of the panels. But the height of the panel on the tab page in focus somehow reduces by a small amount, i.e., when you scroll down to the bottom of the panel, some data gets cut off. But if I switch focus to another tab page, that tab page appears fine. Also, when I switch back to the original tab page, now that also appears fine. Can someone explain why this happens, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think I used to have a similar problem and I solved it with

```
tabControl.TabPages[tabPage].Refresh();
```

after reinitializing the values... But I have no idea why it happens.